# Javascript that opens url in new page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to do a javascript function that opens a URL in a new page, but i need to get same data from a from, example:
i have a text field and i put numbers like 234543256 and when i click submit i need to have a url like

> http://somepage.com/somefile.php?=234543256&someotherthings

So it should be some url + text field datas + some url

to be opened in a new page. Can anyone help?

I have done this until now:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
        <script type="text/javascript" > 

function tracking() {
var url="http://somepage.com/somefile.php?=";
var nr="022300134609";
var endurl="&someotherthings";

var fullurl=url + nr + endurl;
window.open(fullurl);
}
</script>
<form id="test">
<input type="textfield" id="nr" name"test">
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="tracking();">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

But i need to get the value of the "nr" from the form to add.

Comment: <html>
<head></head>
<body>
        <script type="text/javascript" > 

function tracking() {
var url="http://somepage.com/somefile.php?=";
var nr="022300134609";
var endurl="&someotherthings";

var fullurl=url + nr + endurl;
window.open(fullurl);
}
</script>
<form id="test">
<input type="textfield" id="nr" name"test">
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="tracking();">
</form>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window.open() method.
test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function hello()
            {
                var name = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
                // Set url.
                var url = "file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Swe%20Mon/Desktop/test2.html"; // your url string
                // Prepare for parameter.
                var params = "userName=" + name;

                window.open(url + "?" + params); 
                return false;
            }
            </script>
        </head>

        <body>
            Name:<input type="text" id="txtName">
            <button onclick="hello()">Try it</button>
        </body>
        </html>
```

test2.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>


      Test 2 page
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add **target="_blank"** to your form tag. and use **get** as **method**. i.e:

```
<form method="get" target="_blank" name="myform" action="........">

</form>
```

I am assuming by saying submit form in a new page means a new tab..

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this .....it work for you

```
 <html>
<head></head>
<body>
        <script type="text/javascript" > 

function tracking() {
var url="http://somepage.com/somefile.php?=";
var nr=$("#nr").val();
var endurl="&someotherthings";

var fullurl=url + nr + endurl;
window.open(fullurl);
}
</script>
<form id="test">
<input type="textfield" id="nr" name"test">
<input type="button" name="submit" onclick="tracking();">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a javascript function to change your form action : Like in Javascript, it will change your current form action to be submit.

```
function ChnageUrl(targetForm)
{
     var url = targetForm.action;
     var someOtherThings = "someOtherThings";

     var textValue = document.getElmentById('textboxId').value;

     if(url.indexOf("?")>0)
     {
           url = url + "="+textValue+"&"+someOtherThings ;
     }
     else
     {
           url = url + "?="+textValue+"&"+someOtherThings ;
     }
     targetForm.action = url;
}
```

In Html, target="_blank" will open your action url to a new tab.

```
<from method="get" target="_blank" name="myform" action="url" onsubmit="ChangeUrl(this);">
   <input type="text" id="textboxId" name = "textboxId" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</from>
```